# Not able to get single collection type with ?locale={locale_id} parameter from Strapi

Tags: localization, content-management-system, strapi

I'm trying to fetch a single collection type with another locale from Strapi but adding the locale parameter does not help. Is there a way to fetch a single collection type with the same id but with another locale, just like it is done with single types for example.

This is what I was trying:

```
https://myapp.url/api/industry-pages/1?locale=en&populate=deep
```

But now if I want the same type with another locale I would like to do something like this:

```
https://myapp.url/api/industry-pages/1?locale=fi&populate=deep
```

But instead I have to do it like this (returns the other locale even tho there is the locale parameter set to en):

```
https://myapp.url/api/industry-pages/2?locale=en&populate=deep
```

Is there a workaround to this?